# Migration from PrincipalPermission

Tags: .net, security, .net-core

Currently i'm using something like this in my projects:

```
IPermission permission = new PrincipalPermission(null, "MyFancyRole");
permission.Demand();
```

Now with the rise of .NET Core, i try to migrate that project to the latter and have an issue with the security, because I have (nearly) no clue, what would replace the PrincipalPermission in .NET Core.

So has anyone some ideas about that? An educated guess at last?

PS: I say nearly no clue, cause I could surely replace it with `IsInRole("...")` and throw SecurityExceptions if not. I just wanted to know if there's any recommended replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrincipalPermission` was part of Code Access Security, which no longer exists. All identities now are `ClaimsPrincipal`s. So you're right, you would either check for roles with `IsInRole`, or, if you're using ASP.NET you'd use Authorize and [policies](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/index.html).

You can use policies in your own code too, they're not linked to ASP.NET, you can register your classes in DI and inject `IAuthorizationService` in your constructor then call [AuthorizeAsync](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/views.html) and react accordingly.